# Uri matcher странно себя ведет

Tags: android, sqlite, uri, contentprovider

Всем доброго времени суток! 
Пишу маленькое приложение "MyNotes (Мои заметки)". Есть БД SQLite с таблицей заметок, доступ к ней осуществляю через контент провайдер. 
Доступ ко всем записям осуществляется по этому URI: `content://ru.astar.provider.dbnotes/notes`
Доступ к одной записи по конкретному id, выглядит так (c индексом 1, например):
`content://ru.astar.provider.db/notes/#1`
Добавляю в URI matcher вот так:

```
    public static final String AUTORITY = "ru.astar.provider.dbnotes";

    // путь
    public static final String NOTE_PATH = "notes";
    // *************
    uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    uriMatcher.addURI(AUTORITY, NOTE_PATH, URI_NOTES);
    uriMatcher.addURI(AUTORITY, NOTE_PATH + "/#", URI_NOTES_ID);
```

Проверка по uri проходит только на все записи из таблицы, но не проходит почему то по отдельному элементу по id. Вот и сама проверка:

```
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sordOrder) {
    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case URI_NOTES: // общий Uri
            // ставим сортировку по имени если не указана
            Log.d(LOG_TAG + " Общий: ", uri.toString());
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(sordOrder)) {
                sordOrder = NOTE_TITLE + " ASC";
            }
            break;

        case URI_NOTES_ID:
            Log.d(LOG_TAG + " Конкретный ид: ", uri.toString());
            String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
            Log.d("NoteContentProvider", "URI NOTES ID " + id);

            // добавим ID к условиям выборки
            if (selection == null && TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
                selection = NOTE_ID + " = " + id;
            } else {
                selection = selection + " AND " + NOTE_ID + " =? " + id;
            }
            break;

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong URI: " + uri.toString());
    }


    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NOTES, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sordOrder);
    // уведомляем курсор об изменении данных
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), NOTE_CONTENT_URI);
    return cursor;
}
```

Вот ссылка на сам проект в репозитории на GitHub https://github.com/Astar75256/MyNotes.git

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Что значит не проходит проверку? Выведите в лог `uri` перед свичем, чтобы видеть, что там на самом деле, когда вы передаёте id.

Answer (score 0):

см NoteActivity.java: 66-я строчка твоего кода

**PS:**
замени `content://ru.astar.provider.db/notes/#1` на `content://ru.astar.provider.db/notes/1`

*решётка - это плейсхолдер для циферки в uri-matcher(типа шаблон, регулярка и т.п),
но сам uri - не должен иметь решеток*